# On the extension of fields

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $F\subseteq K$ be a finite field extension and let $a_1,..., a_n$ be an $F$-basis for $K$. I want to show that the matrix $A := (tr(a_ia_j))$ is singular if and only if $tr K =0$.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The crux is that if $z=\sum_j b_ja_j$ with $b_j\in F$ is any element of $K$, then
by $F$-linearity of the trace
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
tr(a_1z)\\
tr(a_2z)\\
\vdots\\
tr(a_nz)\end{array}\right)=A
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
b_1\\
b_2\\
\vdots\\
b_n\end{array}\right).
$$
So $A$ is singular if and only if the column vector on the left vanishes for some non-zero $z\in K$ ($z=0$ is equivalent to the column vector of $b_j$:s being all zeros). But if $z\neq0$, then the $F$-span of the products $a_iz, i=1,2,\ldots,n$ is all of $K$, because $K\cdot z=K$.